# Where I can find an exhaustive book about "Definite Clause Grammar" in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, dcg

I wanna learn something more about Definite Clause Grammar in Prolog and I'm searching some book and tutorial online.

I've already saw something on "Learn Prolog Now", "The art of Prolog" and a tutorial on Swi-Prolog, but none of those tells much about them.

Can anyone advice me some exhaustive book about this topic?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is mandatory: https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg.html, but it focus on computational usage of DCG. My preferred Prolog book happens to focus instead on natural language analysis: go google for 'Pereira Shieber' and get the PDF. It's a very good introduction to Prolog and - gradually - to DCGs, and it contains also advanced material - about generalized parsing and performance issues.

*edit* I realized that the [DCG](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dcg/info) tag has a ready to use link to the English downloadable version. By myself, I have the 'dead tree' Italian version, with some extension (and - alas - some typo errors) about the differences required by treatment of Italian.

Comment: How can I get the Italian version?

Comment: @s.dallapalma: I have an Italian version, printed. Alas, I'm in Brescia. Scanning the book would need several hours, not feasible. If you come around, let me know... or try to search for it: ISBN 88-7081-432-7